# Error Append Python

Tags: python

**Hola buenos dias como podria hacer para poder agregar en un append los 3 nombres de los cantantes y no uno solo ?**

```
    beatles = []
beatles.append("John Lennon","paul McCartney", "George Harrison" )

print(beatles)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso no es permitido, en este caso cada elemento es tomado como argumento,mi quieres agregar elementos encierralos en corchetes `[]`

Comment: asi seria ? beatles.append["John Lennon","paul McCartney", "George Harrison" ]

Comment: Nooop, así `beatles.append(["John Lennon","paul McCartney", "George Harrison" ])`

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer eso debes meter los nombres entre `[ ]`, tal que así:

```
beatles = []
beatles.append(["John Lennon","Paul McCartney", "George Harrison"])

print(beatles)
```

Comment: Ah claro iba junto con los parentesis también, ahora me pudo funcionar muchisimas gracias!